# jquery.form.js is not working in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: forms, jquery, internet-explorer-9

I have a simple form with a file upload control. The form will be posted once I click on the `upload` button. I'm trying to do a `jquery-ajax` post, using the [jquery.form.js](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/).

My code is as follows,

```
var options = {
    beforeSubmit: function (formData, jqForm, options) {
        $(".loaderImage").show();
        return true;
    },
    success: function (responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
        $("#result").html(responseText);
    },
    error: function(xhr) { alert(xhr.responseText); }
};
$("#AjaxFileUpload").ajaxSubmit(options);
return false;
```

It works fine in [Google Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome), Firefox and [Internet Explorer 10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_11#Internet_Explorer_10). The problem with [Internet Explorer 9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_9) is, after debugging, it doesn't enter the `success()`. Any pointers on what's going wrong? There are no errors in the console either.

I added the `error` option as well, but the issue is the same, the breakpoint doesn't hit the alert.

I just had a look at the network traffic. There is no POST request going (in Internet Explorer 9) when I click the upload button, but there's a POST request going in Internet Explorer 10.

I cleared the cache and reset browser settings as well. But the issue persists.

Comment: Do you mean [this plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)? Given the great number of jQuery plugins out there, a link is always helpful. The API docs on that link say that you can use the same options as the vanilla jQuery [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method, which includes an `error` function callback option. Have you tried setting that and seeing what the response, status, and error messages (the arguments to the error callback function) are?

Comment: Yes, I'm using that plugin, will update my question with the relevant link. I've updated my question with the `error` part as well

Comment: Any errors in the IE Dev Tools console?

Comment: Nope, no errors, but strangely enough, I just had a look at the network traffic, there is no POST request going (in IE9) when I click the `upload` button, there's a POST request in IE10

Comment: Did you have any progress with this? I'm dealing with the same issue today. I determined there's no network activity in IE<10 unless you provide an "iframeSrc" key to the options object. However, after a lot of analysis, that activity is just an iframe being created and calling to the provided src url. No POST actually occurs, but the 'complete' callback is called...

Answer (score 1):

badZoke, I was experiencing this same problem yesterday and most of today and finally figured out what was causing it (in my case). This might be helpful for your situation, as well:

Internet Explorer has restrictions about form submission when the form is not currently in the DOM. In my case, a user interacted with a button in a modal popup (which also contained the form). When they clicked, the form was removed from the DOM (but still accessible via a js var) and replaced with a loading bar. I then called `myForm.ajaxSubmit(options);` which in IE<10 attempts a submission of that form to a temporary `<iframe/>`. Not allowed unless the form is in the DOM.

If your code above was a simplification of your actual scenario and you were doing something similar to me, this may be your problem. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to see if the `error` callback is invoked:

```
var options = {
    beforeSubmit: function (formData, jqForm, options) {
        $(".loaderImage").show();
        return true;
    },
    success: function (responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
        $("#result").html(responseText);
    },
    error: function(xhr) { alert(xhr.responseText); }
 }; 

$("#AjaxFileUpload").ajaxSubmit(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine on my computer, and I'm using Internet Explorer 9. Maybe the problem is not here.